# Problem with inline messages

Tags: ajax, webforms

I'm hoping to pick your brain on an issue with webform. I did a twig override on a form, that works just fine. The issue lies with the confirmation message. Running with Ajax for an inline confirmation that replaces the form inside a block just empties out the block without placing any content in its place. I also duplicated the issue using the form placed within a node and on its own via webform using view. Reloading the page for messages at the top seem to work fine so long as Ajax isn't involved. It appears to be related to either Ajax or my override. On the off chance its something else, I'll post what I have. Any quick help would be deeply appreciated. Twig is as follows:

```
<div id="contactsection">
  <div class="blocktitlefront">
    <h1 >Contact Me</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row blockbodyfront">
      <form{{ attributes }}>
        {{ title_prefix }}
          <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ element.elements.contactform_usage_description }}<br>
            {{ element.elements.submissioninfo }}
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            {{ element.elements.name }}<br>
            {{ element.elements.email }}<br>
            {{ element.elements.subject }}<br>
            {{ element.elements.message }}<br>
            {{ element.elements.camt_contactform_captcha}}
            {{ element.form_build_id }}
            {{ element.form_token }}
            {{ element.form_id }}
            {{ element.confirmation_message }}
            <br>{{ element.elements.actions }}
          </div>
        {{ title_suffix }}
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using the most up-to-date version of the Webform module.

Comment: It might be worth just building the layout in the Webform UI. If you create a ticket in the Webform issue, I can help you restructure your webform to generate the above markup without overriding the webform template.